# Restore textField data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have several textfields on my view, where I am accepting input from the users. The view contains mandatory and optional fields both. I have put validation for the mandatory fields.Whenever, I check validation for each and every mandatory field. If the validation of the mandatory field fails, UIAlertView pops up. Every-time the AlertView Pops up all the information in the remaining textfileds gets wiped off. 
How do I make sure that the data on the textfield does not get wiped off.

**AlertView I am using**

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Validation"
                                                        message:@"Please enter name."
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
```

**EDIT 1**
I have tried  `delegate:self`, but still the same

**EDIT 2**

```
if(userName.text.length>0 )
{
// Process further
}
else{
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Validation"
                                                            message:@"Please enter name."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release]; 
}
```

Comment: Apart from showing UIAlertView, are you doing any other functionality if validation fails?

Comment: no. this is the only code in else part.

Comment: After else part is there anything in the same method? Because, becomeFirstResponder will clear the text entered, that is why i am asking.

Comment: No nothing.
else{//above code
}

Comment: Can you please post validation code you are using?

Comment: @ParamasivanSamuttiram please find the code.

Comment: @onkar post some more code....

Answer (score 0):

set `UITextFieldDelegate` in your `.h` file and declare `UITextField *txtfldFirstName;`

```
 txtfldFirstName=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 110, 160, 25)];
    txtfldFirstName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    txtfldFirstName.text=@"";
    txtfldFirstName.autocapitalizationType=NO;
    txtfldFirstName.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleLine;
    txtfldFirstName.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:txtfldFirstName];
```

in your action performed

```
if ([txtfldFirstName.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Validation"
                                                            message:@"Please enter name."
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];

}
else
{
// your operation if textfield not empty
}
```

otherwise use

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

 if (textField==txtfldFirstName) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Validation"
                                                                message:@"Please enter name."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];

    }


}
```

Comment: I am using different validations on my view. name,pin(particular length),mobile(size=10),email

so any more generic code ?